# Is there a way to programatically add strings from a xml resource to a list using a loop?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to programatically add strings from a xml resource to a list using a loop?

For example, I have the following string.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1">Text 1</string>
    <string name="string2">Text 2</string>
    <string name="string3">Text 3</string>
</resources>
```

In my MainActivity.kt I want to add the strings to a `mutableListOf<String>` called `stringList`

```
 var i = 1
 do {
      stringList.add(getString(R.string.string<i>)) //Add each R.string.string1->R.string.string3
      i++
 }while (R.string.string<i> != null)
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a string-array may help you:

```
<string-array name="my_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

and its usage:

```
val list = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.my_array).toList()
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the context.resource import?

Comment: `val list = resources.getStringArray(R.array.string).toList() as MutableList<String>`
achieved the results I am looking for. Thanks for the help.